# "[ERROR] <no source info>" in GWT compile when previously compiling made no such error

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I've searched the net but failed to reach the answer.

I found some similar question in Stackoverflow but they cannot be duplicate.

Here is a part of the error message generated in GWT compilation.

> [ERROR] : public interface org.hibernate.Session
>     extends java.lang.Object
>     implements : java.io.Serializable
>
> /*   methods   */
>   public abstract org.hibernate.Transaction beginTransaction() throws org.hibernate.HibernateException
>
> [unresolved] public abstract void cancelQuery() throws Unresolved type 
>   ... on an on...

Some workaround found in many other threads is

1. delete [gwt-unitCache] if previously no such error was generated.
2. or provide right signature as in http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4470

Yes, I've hundred times compiled my gwt project and there was no such error.

Hibernate worked very well and not a bit related to hibernate ORM has been modified.

But I can't figure out why it occurs.

In development mode, everything goes fine, but compilation process gives me that.

Has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I tried hard to narrow down to the root cause, only to fail.

But what's bizarre is that it now begins to compile without error again,

even though what I did is merely revert to my previously-without-error project and adding a set of

candidate snippets one or more of which may have been the cause,

giving no point of error.

It now just works.

That compilation error eroded my Sunday, very strange.